# Sorting the result based on 2 columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two columns Date and Number with null values in date. Can I sort with date and number col together checking if date is null then sort with number.

```
dt             num
3/20/2022       1
3/16/2022       3
3/17/2022       4
3/18/2022       5
NULL            6
NULL            7
3/19/2022       8

*Expected Output*
dt             num
3/16/2022       3
3/17/2022       4
3/18/2022       5
NULL            6
NULL            7
3/19/2022       8
3/20/2022       1
```

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You seem to want to order by date first, and then take the rows witn `null` date and "fit" them among the other rows based on `num`. But that won't work in general - if there is no direct relation between dates and numbers. In your example it works because ordering by date is "almost" the same as ordering by number. Imagine this scenario: four rows (Jan-1, 6), (Jan-2, 2), (Jan-3, 5), (NULL, 1). Where do you fit (NULL, 1), and why? I can give you more complex examples where any answer will contradict itself.

Comment: Another example: (Jan-1, 3), (Jan-2, 6), (Jan-3, 4), (Jan-4, 8), (NULL, 5). Where do you fit the NULL - between Jan-1 and Jan-2, or between Jan-3 and Jan-4 - and **why**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to sort by the date if there is one and if there is not we search the previous row where the date is not null.
This does mean that we are running a sub-query per line so it will be slow for large queries.

> ```
> create table d(
> dt date,
> num int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into d (dt, num)
> select to_date('2022-03-20','YYYY-MM-DD'),1 from dual union all
> select to_date('2022-03-16','YYYY-MM-DD'),3 from dual union all
> select to_date ('2022-03-17','YYYY-MM-DD'), 4 from dual union all
> select  to_date('2022-03-17','YYYY-MM-DD'),5 from dual union all
> select  to_date('2022-03-18','YYYY-MM-DD'),6 from dual union all
> select  to_date('2022-03-16','YYYY-MM-DD'),10 from dual union all
> select  to_date('2022-03-19','YYYY-MM-DD'),9 from dual;
> ```

> ```
> insert into d ( num)
> select     7 from dual union all
> select     8 from dual ;
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   dt,
>   num,
>   ( select dt 
>     from d 
>     where num <= d1.num and dt is not null 
>     order by num desc 
>     fetch next 1 rows only 
>   ) as dt_plus
> from d d1
> order by dt_plus,num;
> ```
>
> ```
> DT        | NUM | DT_PLUS  
> :-------- | --: | :--------
> 16-MAR-22 |   3 | 16-MAR-22
> 16-MAR-22 |  10 | 16-MAR-22
> 17-MAR-22 |   4 | 17-MAR-22
> 17-MAR-22 |   5 | 17-MAR-22
> 18-MAR-22 |   6 | 18-MAR-22
> null      |   7 | 18-MAR-22
> null      |   8 | 18-MAR-22
> 19-MAR-22 |   9 | 19-MAR-22
> 20-MAR-22 |   1 | 20-MAR-22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6167857c806019baf78d396fa536aa4)*

Comment: Thank you so much Kendle for your time and help, if the NULLS are the firs two record then maybe I can use NVL to make it 1/1/2000 . I will try and let you know if it works for all cases

Comment: Glad to help - please accept or upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: Hi Kendle, If I have 1st row with NULL date , it cannot find the previous date. How  can we tweak this query  
1 - null
2 - 5/1/2022
3 - 5/2/2022
4 - 5/3/2022
5 - 5/4/2022
13 - 4/29/2022
14 - 4/30/2022
15 - null

Comment: if 1st record is null, it should  start with lowest date and then do the steps you did in previous query.. so in above example , it will be  13 , 14, 15 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5